# plantilla php remplazar con datos de array

Tags: php, html, template

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo html en un archivo php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{lang}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>{Title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

como verán tengo entre corchetes algunas palabras `{lang}` o `{Title}`.
estoy guardando el archivo php en una variable:

```
$vdata = file_get_contents('path/archivo.php');
```

Tengo un array de la siguiente manera:

```
 array(2) {
    ["lang"]=>
    string(4) "es_ES"
    ["Title"]=>
    string(7) "Mi Pagina Web"
  }
```

como puedo hacer el remplazo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto:
el array esta en `$Dic`

```
foreach ($Dic as $key => $value) {
    $text = str_replace('{'.$key.'}',$value, $vdata);
}
```

aunque no se si es la manera mas optima de hacerlo.